# WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) greyed out

Tags: php, wordpress, bitnami

My Bitnami WordPress AMI (Amazon AWS image) has ended up being set as a HTTP site in Settings > General within the WordPress admin screen. This is greyed out. I can't change it. If I edit it in the `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php` file (simply adding `https`, or deleting those lines completely) then the site stops working.

In addition to changing this file, is there some database element to the required change?  I do have a valid SSL certificate and this is proven by using `https:` specifically when calling the URL and verifying through the browser.

Comment: have you install easySSL plugin ? or edit htaccess file for redirect ssl ?

Comment: Hi, yes I have installed it, I think that is why it is only secure for https://www. and nothing else.

Comment: i think problem is for htaccess , check the file and import code for ssl in htaccess customly

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

The way to change the WordPress domain name configuration is by editing the wp-config.php file you already edited. Your site should be working properly now.

If you want to use SSL certificates and use https when accessing your site, you will need to generate valid certificates and configure Apache to use them. As you can see in the main configuration file (/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf), the default certificates are inside the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf folder. If you substitute the server.crt and server.key files with the new ones, your site will be secure.

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/enable-https-ssl-apache/

You can also generate Let's Encrypt certificates using our HTTPS tool

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool
```

That tool will generate the certificates and configure them in Apache automatically

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/understand-bncert/

I hope this information helps

Comment: Hi. I've tried again editing wp-config.php which has my site name as http. If I change it to https that's the end of the site... It simply stops being accessible over the internet. I can see the rest of what you're saying but if I follow your plan I fall at the first hurdle. It should resolve my issue, should it not? Simply changing it to https in the config file

Comment: Changing the wp-config.php file from http to https shouldn't break the application. You can keep http there and configure Apache with the SSL certificate as I explained above. Once you include the SSL certificate, your site will be secure. You will just need to configure your domain name in the wp-config.php (using http)

Comment: Hi. It does though... The Web page is accessible up until I change it to https in the config file. After that, no more access. As soon as I change it back to http again, it's fine.

Comment: Are you getting a redirection loop when setting https? Maybe there is some mismatch between the HTTPS redirection in Apache and the WordPress' configuration.